# CSS :not() selector - Hide everything from body except one div

Tags: html, css

**Is it possible to hide all body inner elements with CSS 

except intro-class and his child-elements?**

```css
body *:not(.intro > *) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

  <div class="intro">
    <p id="firstname">My name is Donald.</p>
    <p id="hometown">I live in Duckburg.</p>
  </div>

  <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide all direct childs elements of body except `.intro`. Opacity will be apply on an element and all his childs.

```css
body>*:not(.intro) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
  <div class="intro">
    <p id="firstname">My name is Donald.</p>
    <p id="hometown">I live in Duckburg.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="outro">
    <p id="firstname">My name is Mickey.</p>
    <p id="hometown">I live in Mickeyburg.</p>
  </div>
  <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to hide all elements excluding .intro using :not selector, and later to display all childs inside .intro.

```css
body *:not(.intro) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.intro > * {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

  <div class="intro">
    <p id="firstname">My name is Donald.</p>
    <p id="hometown">I live in Duckburg.</p>
  </div>

  <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: The `:not()` selector is in this example no longer needed, since `!important` will overwrite the `*` selector anyways.

Comment: nope, it's still needs, You can run without `:not()` and you'll see that it does not works.

Comment: you did totally another example)))
did you saw code above?

Comment: No, I did not. The principle of overwriting in CSS applies to all elements the same way. https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/BaKGeXr

Comment: You can also get rid of the `!important`, since the following `style-rules` in CSS have the ability to overwrite the leading ones anyways. https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/qBZQzBN

Comment: you did totally ANOTHER example and trying to prove something...that's funny))

Comment: You right. `opacity` seems to behave differently than `visibility`. Since the parent container [`.intro`] is also set to `opacity: 0`, it's children don't have the ability to overwrite that, when in comes to the `opacity` property. But that is a *property specific behaviour* and can easily be avoided. This criticism was not meant to show that you did wrong, but that OP and others would know better. > https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/QWNJXbz

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `:not` for all the elements you want to show. Simply using `:not` pseudo class on `.intro` will not `show` its `child` as well since you are using `*`

`*` Will select all the elements on that page.

```
body *:not(.intro):not(#firstname):not(#hometown) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**Live Demo:**

```css
body *:not(.intro):not(#firstname):not(#hometown) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
  <div class="intro">
    <p id="firstname">My name is Donald.</p>
    <p id="hometown">I live in Duckburg.</p>
  </div>
  <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
</body>
```